# nginx and PHP 7 - Error bad gateway 502 on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, typo3, php-7, bad-gateway

I'm just testing a Raspberry Pi 3 and nginx / PHP7 / APC-Cache for TYPO3 8, most of the time it works fine, but sometimes I get the error "bad gateway" 502.

Has anyone tips / infos for me? I believe it is the nginx "sites-available" settings or caching.

**Error.log**

```
recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream
```

Comment: Possible answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/543999/nginx-errors-recv-failed-104-connection-reset-by-peer-while-reading-respon

Comment: Hi, I test the Answer, but it dont work :(